# bbcode form editor into db as html

Tags: php, html, bbcode

I have a form with custom BB code editor. The problem I have is: If I want to make a bold text it gives me out `[b]text[/b]`. So that is useless in usage after submiting form. I have a preview  which shows how it looks. 
Here is my code: [Code](http://pastebin.com/zecK8cQy)
And this goes into form itself:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#fulls").bbcode();
    process();
  });

  var bbcode="";
  function process()
  {
        if (bbcode != $("#fulls").val())
        {
            bbcode = $("#fulls").val();
            $.get('php/bbParser.php',
            {
                bbcode: bbcode
            },
            function(txt){
                $("#full").html(txt);
                })

        }
        setTimeout("process()", 2000);

  }



</script>
```

The textare where is the orginal with [b]Text[/b].

```
<textarea name="fulls" id="fulls""></textarea>
```

And here is the preview:

```
<div name="full" id="full" ></div>
```

I have thinked of two options in this case myself.
1. Create a code that replaces the [b]Text[/b] when I want to get it out of DB.
2. To output the preview into another textare which is submited to DB with all the correct html.

In my opinion the option 2 is easier, but I don't know if its oky to add html into DB table.

Comment: Never pass a string to `setTimeout`. That particular example can be written as `setTimeout(process, 2000)`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to store the BB code in your database, in case you want to be able to easily edit it later.

A quick Google search will provide scripts that can easily convert BB code to HTML on demand.

Comment: Should I use javascript or php to convert it to html? And also if there will be a lot of bbcodes when I want to get them out of db. Wouldn't it make my server slow?

Comment: I'd go with javascript - it's a nice practice to defer whatever processing you can to client-side if your server resources are limited. But if your server isn't maxed out I'd consider doing it server-side for a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely safer with Option 1. Storing BBCode in the database means that there is a limited number of potential avenues for attack on your site, because the number of total tags you support is very narrow.